# Equivalent of creating objects in Haskell

Tags: oop, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to understand how the following are used:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

From my understanding these are *parameterized algebraic data types*. Coming from an OO background, I would now like to create an instance of these objects. If I do something like:

```
x = Maybe 10
```

Is that now a subclass/sub-algebraic-data-type, or wondering what that object is called. I would assume it is a *type* of some sort. If so, then I am wondering how to create an *instance* of `x`. In OO land I would do:

```
myinstance = new x
```

This is where coming to Haskell gets me lost and I'm not sure where to search. A few questions to summarize:

1. What kind of object `x` is above. If `Maybe` is a parameterized data type, then x is *~something~* type, not sure.
2. How to create an instance of `x`.
3. What is the instance of `x` for Maybe, since we passed it 10. Wondering, if the instance value is 10 and has type Int.

Comment: Well in a lot of programming languages `new` is only used to allocate objects on the heap, etc. It is thus some sort of "malloc", if you allocate on the stack, then you typically do not use `new`.

Comment: Another vital difference is that it is an immutable object. So whether it is `myinstance`, or another value, does not matter, since you later can not alter the attributes of the element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as `Maybe 10` in Haskell. There is `Maybe Int`, which is a *type*.

We create a *value* of a certain type, *directly*, as

```
x :: Maybe Int
x = Just 10
```

or

```
y :: Maybe Int
y = Nothing
```

Simple and direct.

---

*edit:* `Maybe` is a *type constructor*. `Just` and `Nothing` are *data constructors*. By writing `Maybe Int` we "create" a type. There can't be a definition `z :: Maybe ; z = .....`.

This is known as "kind": the kind of `Maybe` is `* -> *`, while e.g. `Int`'s is `*` and so is `Maybe Int`'s. Try `:k` at GHCi prompt to see this:

```
~> :k Int
Int :: *

~> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *

~> :k Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
```

Of course we don't actually create a new type when we write `"Maybe Int`, it's just that `Maybe` by itself is not a type of things yet (types of "things" have kind `*`).

The definition for `Maybe` is what creates the types `Maybe a`, for any `a` we might use. This is known as *parametric* polymorphism.

So in Haskell, we don't have objects (in the OOP sense). We have values and types.

Comment: @LancePollard I agree with you that there are no expressions classified by the type `Maybe`, but not for the reason you say. `Maybe` is indeed a (type) constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of object x is above. If Maybe is a parameterized data type, then x is ~something~ type, not sure.

You can not construct a `Maybe 10`, you can for example construct a `Just 10`. In case `10` is here an `Int` (well technically it can be *any* numerical type, but let us ignore that for now), then you constructed a `Maybe Int`.

Note that `a` in `Maybe a`, is one *meta* level higher: it works with types. Hence `a` is a *type* parameter. It thus does not take as value `10`, but for example `Int`.

What you *can* do however is define a *type alias* for `Maybe Int`, for example:

```
type X = Maybe Int
```

Note that we here use `type` as a type alias, *not* `data` to construct a data type.

Types (and type aliasses) always start with an upper case, so we can not define a type `x`, only a type `X`. A type has *no* default constructor (which is typically the case in OO programming languages).

> How to create an instance of x.

Haskell can derive the most generic type of an expression itself. We thus write an expression that has the type of `Maybe Int`, so for example

```
Just 10
```

In case the type would be too generic (here it will be `Num a => Maybe a`), we can give a hint to Haskell by using two consecutive colons (`::`), for eample:

```
Just 10 :: Maybe Int
```

or since we already introduced the type alias `X`:

```
Just 10 :: X
```

> What is the instance of x for Maybe, since we passed it 10. Wondering, if the instance value is 10 and has type Int.

Welll as said before, types in Haskell have *no* default constructor. We here have two candidates: `Just n` with `n` an `Int` (in case we use type `X`), or `Nothing`. So we pick one of the two:

```
Just 10 :: X
Nothing :: X
```

Since you can not *change* the state of an object anymore after you constructed it (i.e. all objects in Haskell are immutable), that means that it would be strange that a default constructor sets some initial data, and then later methods would change that object.

You can therefore see a *data constructor* (here `Just` and `Nothing`) as a labelled container that holds a group of parameters together in a container, and labels it with what constructor was used. So a graphical view of the objects would be:

```
+------+   +---------+
| Just |   | Nothing |
+------+   +---------+
|   o  |
+---|--+
    |
    v
 +----+
 | 10 |
 +----+
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write an algebraic type definition as

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

the LHS is a type construction expression (it states that `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`), and the RHS is a disjunction of alternatives each one being a *value constructor*, so for type `Maybe a`, `Just` is an unary constructor that creates an object of this type, and `Nothing` is the nullary one.